# Amplifier stopped working completely after changing op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

After replacing op-amp given in the picture

[image]

with LM386L the amplifier pretty much stopped working entirely. There is only a faint sound on the output - as if the gain was way below 1.

Given the characteristics and my ignorance I have no dea why this happened.

Comment: What was wrong before you replaced the op-amp?

Comment: According to the datasheet of [LM358](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM358.pdf) and [LM386](http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/indexerfiles/Datasheet-017/DSA00289258.pdf) these are fairy different devices, that require different component configurations to work as expected.

Comment: Scott, nothing in particular was wrong - as far as I know LM386 is more suitable for such applications, therefore I wanted to try it with hope of getting better performance.

Comment: The LM386 is not an opamp, it's specifically an audio power amplifier (for small values of "power").

Comment: And it doesn't have the same pinout as an opamp. For example, the output appears at pin 5, not pin 6. Do check the datasheet before you try. You can't do this.

Comment: Jippie, Dave, EJP thank you. It's just my ignorance is vast. I got it working, thanks. Simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make the point clear and actually put an answer to this question. (**see all the comments by Dave, Jippie et al.**) They are totally different ICs. The 358 is is dual op amp (it has two separate op amps in the same 8 pin package). The 386 is an audio amplifier. They have different pinouts and cannot be interchanged.

[image]

---

[image]